# Switching the order of paste() in piping in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and I would like to paste the string "exampletext" in front of each file name within the path.

```
   csvList <- list.files(path = "./csv_by_subject") %>%
      paste0("*exampletext")
```

Currently this code renders things like "csv*exampletext" and I want it to be *exampletextcsv". I would like to continue to using dplyr and piping - help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, the pipe is not necessary here. But if you do want to use it, you just have to specify that the second argument to `paste0` is "the thing you are piping", which you do using a period (.)

```
list.files(path = "./csv_by_subject") %>%
      paste0("*exampletext", .)
```

Answer (score 0):

`paste0('exampletext', csvList)` should do the trick. It's not necessarily using `dplyr` and piping, but it's taking advantage of the vectorization features that R provides.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to paste *exampletext before all of the file names, you can reverse the order of what you're doing now using paste0 and passing the second argument as list.files.  paste0 can handle vectors as the second argument and will apply the paste to each element.

```
 csvList <- paste0("*exampletext", list.files(path = "./csv_by_subject"))
```

This returns a few examples from a local folder on my machine:

```
csvList

  [1] "*exampletext_error_metric.m"                                                                                      
  [2] "*exampletext_get_K_clusters.m"         
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one point to neilfws answer, if you are using native pipe, instead of magrittr pipe, then you must make some adaptations

Instead of using the dot, you must use underscore. The reason is that there are some differences between the native pipe and magrittr pipe, as you can see in this post: [What are the differences between R's native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe)

The difference we are looking at is the different placeholder. In magrritr, the placeholder is ".", but in the native pipe, the placeholder is "_". You must indicate to paste0() function these change, doing as follows:

```
list.files(path = "./csv_by_subject") |>
      paste0("*exampletext", . = _)
```

Here's an example of how these works:

```
library(magrittr)

vector <- c("a", "b", "c")

# paste0() without switching order
vector %>%
  paste0("test:")
[1] "atest:" "btest:" "ctest:"

# paste0() switching order with magrittr pipe, using "." placeholder
vector %>%
  paste0("test: ", .)
[1] "test: a" "test: b" "test: c"

# paste0() switching order with native pipe, using "." placeholder
vector |> 
  paste0("test: ", .)
Error: object '.' not found

# paste0() switching order with native pipe, using "_" placeholder
vector |> 
  paste0("test: ", _)
Error in paste0("test: ", "_") : 
  pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument (<input>:2:3)

# paste0() switching order with native pipe, using "_" placeholder 
# and indicating that to paste0() function
vector |> 
  paste0("test: ", . = _)
[1] "test: a" "test: b" "test: c"
```