# What are the differences between R's native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr, r-faq

In R 4.1 (May 2021) a native pipe operator was introduced that is "more streamlined" than previous implementations. I already noticed one difference between the native `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`, namely `2 %>% sqrt` works but `2 |> sqrt` doesn't and has to be written as `2 |> sqrt()`. Are there more differences and pitfalls to be aware of when using the native pipe operator?

Comment: Have you checked out the `?pipeOp` and the `?"%>%"` hep pages? That's a good source of info.

Comment: official tidyverse blog post on the topic: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/

Answer (score 107):

| Topic | Magrittr *2.0.3* | Base *4.3.0* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Operator** | `%>%` `%<>%` `%$%` `%!>%` `%T>%` | `|>` (since 4.1.0) |
| **Function call** | `1:3 %>% sum()` | `1:3 |> sum()` |
|  | `1:3 %>% sum` | *Needs brackets / parentheses* |
|  | `` 1:3 %>% `+`(4) `` | *Some functions are not supported* |
| Insert on first empty place | `mtcars %>% lm(formula = mpg ~ disp)` | `mtcars |> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp)` |
| **Placeholder** | `.` | `_` (since 4.2.0) |
|  | `mtcars %>% lm(mpg ~ disp, data = . )` | `mtcars |> lm(mpg ~ disp, data = _ )` |
|  | `mtcars %>% lm(mpg ~ disp, . )` | *Needs named argument* |
|  | `1:3 %>% setNames(., .)` | *Can only appear once* |
|  | `1:3 %>% {sum(sqrt(.))}` | *Nested calls are not allowed* |
| Extraction call | `mtcars %>% .$cyl` `mtcars %>% {.$cyl[[3]]}` or `mtcars %$% cyl[[3]]` | `mtcars |> _$cyl` (since 4.3.0) `mtcars |> _$cyl[[3]]` |
| **Environment** | `%>%` has *additional function environment* use:`"x" %!>% assign(1)` | `"x" |> assign(1)` |
| **Create Function** | `top6 <- . %>% sort() %>% tail()` | *Not possible* |
| **Speed** | Slower because *Overhead of function call* | Faster because *Syntax transformation* |

Many differences and limitations disappear when using `|>` in combination with an (anonymous) function:
`1 |> (\(.) .)()`
`-3:3 |> (\(.) sum(2*abs(.) - 3*.^2))()`

Have also a look at: [How to pipe purely in base R ('base pipe')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329335) and [What are the differences and use cases of the five Magrittr Pipes %>%, %<>%, %$%, %!>% and %T>%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326742).

---

**Needs brackets**

```
library(magrittr)

1:3 |> sum
#Error: The pipe operator requires a function call as RHS

1:3 |> sum()
#[1] 6

1:3 |> approxfun(1:3, 4:6)()
#[1] 4 5 6

1:3 %>% sum
#[1] 6

1:3 %>% sum()
#[1] 6

1:3 %>% approxfun(1:3, 4:6)  #But in this case empty parentheses are needed
#Error in if (is.na(method)) stop("invalid interpolation method") :
1:3 %>% approxfun(1:3, 4:6)()
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Some **functions** are **not [supported](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e3b297a64f932d402dc59727c088386cae6a8112/src/main/names.c#L1007)**,
but some still can be called by placing them in brackets, call them via the function `::`, use the placeholder, call it in a function or define a link to the function.

```
1:3 |> `+`(4)
#Error: function '+' not supported in RHS call of a pipe

1:3 |> (`+`)(4)
#[1] 5 6 7

1:3 |> base::`+`(4)
#[1] 5 6 7

1:3 |>  `+`(4, e2 = _)
#[1] 5 6 7

1 |> (`+`)(2) |> (`*`)(3) #(1 + 2) * 3  or `*`(`+`(1, 2), 3) and NOT 1 + 2 * 3
#[1] 9

1:3 |> (\(.) . + 4)()
#[1] 5 6 7

fun <- `+`
1:3 |> fun(4)
#[1] 5 6 7

1:3 %>% `+`(4)
#[1] 5 6 7
```

Placeholder **needs named argument**

```
2 |> setdiff(1:3, _)
#Error: pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument

2 |> setdiff(1:3, y = _)
#[1] 1 3

2 |> (\(.) setdiff(1:3, .))()
#[1] 1 3

2 %>% setdiff(1:3, .)
#[1] 1 3

2 %>% setdiff(1:3, y = .)
#[1] 1 3
```

Also for variadic functions with `...` (dot-dot-dot) arguments, the placeholder `_` needs to be used as a named argument.

```
"b" |>  paste("a", _, "c")
#Error: pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument

"b" |>  paste("a", . = _, "c")
#[1] "a b c"

"b" |>  (\(.) paste("a", ., "c"))()
#[1] "a b c"
```

Placeholder can **only appear once**

```
1:3 |> setNames(nm = _)
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3 

1:3 |> setNames(object = _, nm = _)
#Error in setNames(object = "_", nm = "_") : 
#  pipe placeholder may only appear once

1:3 |> (\(.) setNames(., .))()
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3 

1:3 |> list() |> setNames(".") |> with(setNames(., .))
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3 

1:3 |> list(. = _) |> with(setNames(., .))
#1 2 3
#1 2 3

1:3 %>% setNames(object = ., nm = .)
#1 2 3
#1 2 3

1:3 %>% setNames(., .)
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3
```

**Nested calls** are not allowed

```
1:3 |> sum(sqrt(x=_))
#Error in sum(1:3, sqrt(x = "_")) : invalid use of pipe placeholder

1:3 |> (\(.) sum(sqrt(.)))()
#[1] 4.146264

1:3 %>% {sum(sqrt(.))}
#[1] 4.146264
```

**Extraction call**
Experimental feature since 4.3.0. The placeholder `_` can now also be used in the rhs of a forward pipe `|>` expression as the first argument in an extraction call, such as `_$coef`. More generally, it can be used as the head of a chain of extractions, such as `_$coef[[2]]`*

```
mtcars |> _$cyl
mtcars |> _[["cyl"]]
mtcars |> _[,"cyl"]
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

mtcars |> _$cyl[[4]]
#[1] 6

mtcars %>% .$cyl
mtcars %>% .[["cyl"]]
mtcars %>% .[,"cyl"]
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

#mtcars %>% .$cyl[4] #gives mtcars[[4]]
mtcars %>% .$cyl %>% .[4]
#[1] 6
```

No **additional Environment**

```
assign("x", 1)
x
#[1] 1

"x" |> assign(2)
x
#[1] 2

"x" |> (\(x) assign(x, 3))()
x
#[1] 2

1:3 |> assign("x", value=_)
x
#[1] 1 2 3

"x" %>% assign(4)
x
#[1] 1 2 3

4 %>% assign("x", .)
x
#[1] 1 2 3

"x" %!>% assign(4) #Use instead the eager pipe
x
#[1] 4

5 %!>% assign("x", .)
x
#[1] 5
```

**Create a Function**

```
top6 <- . %>% sort() %>% tail()
top6(c(1:10,10:1))
#[1]  8  8  9  9 10 10
```

---

**Other possibilities:**
A different pipe operator and different placeholder could be realized with the **Bizarro pipe** `->.;` what is not a pipe (see [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67868289/10488504)) which is overwriting `.`

```
1:3 ->.; sum(.)
#[1] 6

mtcars ->.; .$cyl
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

mtcars ->.; .$cyl[4]
#[1] 6

1:3 ->.; setNames(., .)
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3 

1:3 ->.; sum(sqrt(x=.))
#[1] 4.146264

"x" ->.; assign(., 5)
x
#[1] 5

6 ->.; assign("x", .)
x
#[1] 6

1:3 ->.; . + 4
#[1] 5 6 7

1 ->.; (`+`)(., 2) ->.; (`*`)(., 3)
#[1] 9

1 ->.; .+2 ->.; .*3
#[1] 9
```

and evaluates different.

```
x <- data.frame(a=0)
f1 <- \(x) {message("IN 1"); x$b <- 1; message("OUT 1"); x}
f2 <- \(x) {message("IN 2"); x$c <- 2; message("OUT 2"); x}

x ->.; f1(.) ->.; f2(.)
#IN 1
#OUT 1
#IN 2
#OUT 2
#  a b c
#1 0 1 2

x |> f1() |> f2()
#IN 2
#IN 1
#OUT 1
#OUT 2
#  a b c
#1 0 1 2

f2(f1(x))
#IN 2
#IN 1
#OUT 1
#OUT 2
#  a b c
#1 0 1 2
```

Or define a **custom pipe operator** which is setting `.` to the value of the lhs in a new environment and evaluates rhs in it. But here values in the calling environment could not be created or changed.

```
`:=` <- \(lhs, rhs) eval(substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))

mtcars := .$cyl[4]
#[1] 6

1:3 := setNames(., .)
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3 

1:3 := sum(sqrt(x=.))
#[1] 4.146264

"x" := assign(., 6)
x
#Error: object 'x' not found

1 := .+2 := .*3
#[1] 9
```

So another try is assigning lhs to the placeholder `.` in the calling environment and evaluate the rhs in the calling environment. But here `.` will be removed from calling environment in case it was already there.

```
`?` <- \(lhs, rhs) {
  on.exit(if(exists(".", parent.frame())) rm(., envir = parent.frame()))
  assign(".", lhs, envir=parent.frame())
  eval.parent(substitute(rhs))
}

mtcars ? .$cyl[4]
#[1] 6

1:3 ? setNames(., .)
#1 2 3 
#1 2 3 

1:3 ? sum(sqrt(x=.))
#[1] 4.146264

"x" ? assign(., 6)
x
#[1] 6

1 ? .+2 ? .*3
#[1] 9
```

Another possibility will be to replace all `.` with lhs so that during evaluation `.` does not exists anymore as a name.

```
`%|>%` <- \(lhs, rhs)
  eval.parent(eval(call('substitute', substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))))

mtcars %|>% .$cyl[4]
[1] 6

1:3 %|>% setNames(., .)
1 2 3 
1 2 3

1:3 %|>% sum(sqrt(x=.))
[1] 4.146264

"x" %|>% assign(., 6)
x
#[1] 6

1 %|>% .+2 %|>% .*3
#[1] 7
```

The name of the used operator influences the operator precedence: See [Same function but using for it the name %>% causes a different result compared when using the name :=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155705).
For more advanced options see: [Write own / custom pipe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160601).

---

**Speed**

```
library(magrittr)

`:=` <- \(lhs, rhs) eval(substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))

`?` <- \(lhs, rhs) {
  on.exit(if(exists(".", parent.frame())) rm(., envir = parent.frame()))
  assign(".", lhs, envir=parent.frame())
  eval.parent(substitute(rhs))
}

`%|>%` <- \(lhs, rhs)
  eval.parent(eval(call('substitute', substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))))


x <- 42
bench::mark(min_time = 0.2, max_iterations = 1e8
, x
, identity(x)
, "|>" = x |> identity()
, "|> _" = x |> identity(x=_)
, "->.;" = {x ->.; identity(.)}
, "|> f()" = x |> (\(y) identity(y))()
, "%>%" = x %>% identity
, ":=" = x := identity(.)
, "list." = x |> list() |> setNames(".") |> with(identity(.))
, "%|>%" = x %|>% identity(.)
, "?" = x ? identity(.)
)
```

Result

```
   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`   n_itr  n_gc
   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>   <int> <dbl>
 1 x            31.08ns   48.2ns 19741120.        0B     7.46 2646587     1
 2 identity(x) 491.04ns 553.09ns  1750116.        0B    27.0   323575     5
 3 |>          497.91ns 548.08ns  1758553.        0B    27.3   322408     5
 4 |> _        506.87ns 568.92ns  1720374.        0B    26.9   320003     5
 5 ->.;        725.03ns 786.04ns  1238488.        0B    21.2   233864     4
 6 |> f()      972.07ns   1.03µs   929926.        0B    37.8   172288     7
 7 %>%           2.76µs   3.05µs   315448.        0B    37.2    59361     7
 8 :=            3.02µs   3.35µs   288025.        0B    37.0    54561     7
 9 list.         5.19µs   5.89µs   166721.        0B    36.8    31752     7
10 %|>%          6.01µs   6.86µs   143294.        0B    37.0    27076     7
11 ?             30.9µs  32.79µs    30074.        0B    31.3     5768     6
```

Comment: Amazingly comprehensive.  Note that `1:3 |> list() |> setNames(".") |> with(setNames(., .))` can be written as
`1:3 |> list(. = _) |> with(setNames(., .))` or even 
`1:3 |> setNames(nm = _)`

Comment: Thanks for the variants also using the `_` placeholder! Maybe I should change to another function as there is no need to use the placeholder on two places here with `setNames`.

Answer (score 74):

In R 4.1, there was no placeholder syntax for the native pipe. Thus, there was no equivalent of the `.` placeholder of magrittr and thus the following was impossible with `|>`.

```
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") %>% grepl("at", .)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

As of R 4.2, the native pipe can use `_` as a placeholder but *only with named arguments*.

```
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> grepl("at", x = _)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The `.` and magrittr is still more flexible as `.` can be repeated and appear in expressions.

```
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") %>% 
  paste(., ., toupper(.)) 
#[1] "dogs dogs DOGS" "cats cats CATS" "rats rats RATS"

c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |>
  paste(x = "no", y = _) 
# Error in paste(x = "_", y = "_") : pipe placeholder may only appear once
```

It is also not clear how to use `|>` with a function that takes in unnamed variadic arguments (i.e., `...`). In this `paste()` example, we can make up `x` and `y` arguments to trick the placeholder in the correct place, but that feels hacky.

```
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |>
  paste(x = "no", y = _) 
#[1] "no dogs" "no cats" "no rats"
```

Here are additional ways to work around the place holder limitations-

1. Write a separate function

```
find_at = function(x) grepl("at", x)
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> find_at()
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

2. Use an anonymous function

   a) Use the "old" syntax

   ```
   c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> {function(x) grepl("at", x)}()
   ```

   b) Use the *new* anonymous function syntax

   ```
   c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> {\(x) grepl("at", x)}()
   ```
3. Specify the first parameter by name. This relies on the fact that the native pipe pipes into the first *unnamed* parameter, so if you provide a name for the first parameter it "overflows" into the second (and so on if you specify more than one parameter by name)

```r
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> grepl(pattern="at")
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

- Examples 1 and 2 taken from - https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/new-features-r410-pipe-anonymous-functions/
- Example 3 taken from https://mobile.twitter.com/rlangtip/status/1409904500157161477

Answer (score 44):

The base R pipe `|>` added in R 4.1.0 "just" does functional composition. I.e. we can see that its use *really* is just the same as the functional call:

```
> 1:5 |> sum()             # simple use of |>
[1] 15
> deparse(substitute( 1:5 |> sum() ))
[1] "sum(1:5)"
>
```

That has some consequences:

- it makes it a little faster
- it makes it a little simpler and more robust
- it makes it a little more restrictive: `sum()` here needs the parens for a proper call
- it limits uses of the 'implicit' data argument

This leads to possible use of `=>` which is currently "available but not active" (for which you need to set the enviornment variable `_R_USE_PIPEBIND_`, and which may change for R 4.2.0).

(This was first offered as answer to a question duplicating this [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821210/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-r) and I just copied it over as suggested.)

*Edit:* As the follow-up question on 'what is `=>`' comes up, here is a quick follow-up. *Note that this operator is subject to change.*

```
> Sys.setenv("_R_USE_PIPEBIND_"=TRUE)
> mtcars |> subset(cyl == 4) |> d => lm(mpg ~ disp, data = d)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
     40.872       -0.135  

> deparse(substitute(mtcars |> subset(cyl==4) |> d => lm(mpg ~ disp, data = d)))
[1] "lm(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))"
>
```

The `deparse(substitute(...))` is particularly nice here.

Comment: Implicit data argument is `.` from magrittr? What do you mean by possible use of `=>`? would pipebind be like `%<>%`?

Comment: Yes. There are a few example flying around of using `=>` to assign a data element _explicitly_ to a named variable, say `x`, and use that in, say, `lm(...., data=x)`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what `=>` does but I suppose that is for a separate question.

Comment: Exactly.  And it is also temporary. But I'll toss in a quick edit.

Answer (score 35):

The native pipe is implemented as a syntax transformation and so `2 |> sqrt()` has no discernible overhead compared to `sqrt(2)`, whereas `2 %>% sqrt()` comes with a small penalty.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sqrt(1), 
  2 |> sqrt(), 
  3 %>% sqrt()
)

# Unit: nanoseconds
#          expr  min     lq    mean median   uq   max neval
#       sqrt(1)  117  126.5  141.66  132.0  139   246   100
#       sqrt(2)  118  129.0  156.16  134.0  145  1792   100
#  3 %>% sqrt() 2695 2762.5 2945.26 2811.5 2855 13736   100
```

You see how the expression `2 |> sqrt()` passed to `microbenchmark` is parsed as `sqrt(2)`. This can also be seen in

```
quote(2 |> sqrt())
# sqrt(2)
```

Answer (score 18):

One difference is their placeholder, `_` in base R, `.` in `magrittr`.

---

Since [R 4.2.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html), the base R pipe has a placeholder for piped-in values, `_`, similar to `%>%`'s `.`, but its use is restricted to named arguments, and can only be used once per call.

> It is now possible to use a named argument with the placeholder _ in the rhs call to specify where the lhs is to be inserted. The placeholder can only appear once on the rhs.

To reiterate [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638063/13460602)'s example, you can now use `_` as a named argument on the right-hand side to refer to the left-hand side of the formula:

```r
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> 
    grepl("at", x = _)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

but it has to be named:

```r
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> 
    grepl("at", _)
#Error: pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument
```

and cannot appear more than once (to overcome this issue, one can still use the solutions provided by [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638063/13460602)):

```r
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") |> 
  expand.grid(x = _, y = _)
# Error in expand.grid(x = "_", y = "_") : pipe placeholder may only appear once
```

While this is possible with `magrittr`:

```r
library(magrittr)
c("dogs", "cats", "rats") %>% 
  expand.grid(x = ., y = .)
#     x    y
#1 dogs dogs
#2 cats dogs
#3 rats dogs
#4 dogs cats
#5 cats cats
#6 rats cats
#7 dogs rats
#8 cats rats
#9 rats rats
```

Comment: Does it make any sense to restrict the use for just once? Do they have a plan to remove this constraint?

Comment: If I had to guess (I'm not R-core), it's because these operators (`|>`, etc) rewrite the syntax so that `longcalc() |> quux(x = _)` into `quux(x = longcalc())`, and they don't want `longcalc() |> quux(x=_, y=)` to translate into double the calc with `quux(x=longcalc(), y=longcalc())` (where the second is a redundant and double-the-time call). Just a guess, though. @GitHunter0