# How to include binary arithmetic operators in native pipe

Tags: r, pipe, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to integrate binary arithmetic operators in the native pipe.

Reproducible example:

```
# without pipe
round(sample(1:2, 1) / 3, 2)
## [1] 0.33

# with pipe
1:2 |> sample(1) / 3 |> round(2)
## [1] 0.3333333 # round is ignored
1:2 |> (sample(1) / 3) |> round(2)
## Error: function '(' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
1:2 |> sample(1) |> '/'(3) |> round(2)
## Error: function '/' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

How can I achieve the same result with a pipe?

Comment: Your example isn't tidy enough: 1 |> `:`(2) |> sample(1) |> `/`(3) |> round(2)

Comment: Throws an error: "Error: unexpected ':' in "1 |> :""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# use aliases of the magrittr package
1:2 |> sample() |> divide_by(3) |> round(3)

# use map to apply a function to each element
1:2 |> sample() |> map_dbl(~ .x / 3) |> round(3)

# calling the operator as a function using backticks
1:2 |> sample() |> (`/`)(3) |> round(3)
```

Comment: question is asked how to xxxxxx in "native pipe"

Comment: Thanks. I updated the example to the new native pipe

Comment: I especially like the last method! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The new native pipe does have a (imho) strange behaviour. You could use an anonymous function:

```r
1:2  |>  {\(x) sample(x, 1) / 3}() |>  round(2)
#> [1] 0.33
```

Take a look at this question: [What are the differences between R's new native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe)