# Argument placeholder for base R pipe |>

Tags: r, pipe

I'm trying to understand how `|>` works, and how it compares to the `magrittr` `%>%`.
Consider the following code, which is rather unpleasant to look at / debug:

```
toy <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), type = c("apple", "pear", "orange"))

set.seed(1)
subset(toy, type == "apple")[sample(nrow(subset(toy, type == "apple")), 1),]
#>   a  type
#>   1 1 apple
```

The documentation of `|>` says:

> Pipe notation allows a nested sequence of calls to be written in a way
> that may make the sequence of processing steps easier to follow.

Which makes me believe something like

```
toy |>
  subset(type == "apple") |>
  `[.data.frame`(sample(nrow(.), 1),)
```

is possible, but doesn't work, as the dot is meaningless here. Note, `[.data.frame` seems to bypass the `[` restriction of the RHS of `|>`. I've tried to find the source code for `|>` by running `*backtick*|>*backtick*` in the console, but that results in `Error: object '|>' not found`.

Using the `magrittr` pipe, a placeholder `.` can be used like this:

```
library(magrittr)
toy %>%
  subset(type == "apple") %>%
  `[`(sample(nrow(.), 1),)
#>   a  type
#>   1 1 apple
```

#### Question

How to properly write nested calls using base R pipe `|>`?

Comment: `toy |>
  subset(type == "apple") |> {\(.)
  ``[.data.frame``(sample(nrow(.), 1),)}()`

Comment: @Eyayaw Use of `{` results in an error: `toy |> {}`  >> `{ is not supported in RHS of |>`

Comment: `toy |> subset(type == "apple") |> (function(x) {x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ]})()`

Comment: It works for me. Try this example: `mtcars|>
    subset(am == 1) |> {\(.)
        ``[.data.frame``(., sample(nrow(.), 1), )}()`

Comment: There is no source code for `|>`.  Unlike `%>%`, it is not an operator in that sense.  It is handled completely by the parser.  You can see this if you do something like `deparse(quote(toy |>
  subset(type == "apple")))`, which gives `"subset(toy, type == \"apple\")"`.

Comment: @user2554330 Ah, that's clearer than *"syntax transformation"* mentioned in the help file. So I shouldn't expect the placeholder `=>` to behave anything like magrittr's `.` placeholder (yet) if I want to refer to anything other than the top level in RHS.

Comment: base R native pipe `|>` now have a placeholder, `_`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72004083/13460602).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
toy <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), type = c("apple", "pear", "orange"))

set.seed(1)

toy |> subset(type == "apple") |> 
(\(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ])()
 a  type
1 1 apple

toy |> subset(type == "apple") |> 
(\(x) `[.data.frame`(x, sample(nrow(x), 1), ))()
 a  type
1 1 apple
```

Comment: Constructing and calling an anonymous function does work, thanks for the answer.  Would it be correct to say "the base R pipe does not support placeholder arguments natively, but they can be constructed by formulating and calling anonymous functions"? Also - I'm a bit confused why `(` after `|>`  does not throw an error. both `(` and `function` are not supported as RHS independently, but used together it works

Comment: Yes, as of now, the base pipe Op does not support a placeholder. There is an experimental placeholder option that you can turn on with `Sys.setenv`. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67821421/9782217) SO answer.  You can use `{` or `(` as a delimiter interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

As of R version 4.2.0. an argument placeholder is available for the base pipe. From the R News page:

> In a forward pipe `|>` expression it is now possible to use a named argument with the placeholder `_` in the rhs call to specify where the lhs is to be inserted. The placeholder can only appear once on the rhs.

This however does not work for a nested function call like this.

As far as I know the canonical way to do this in base R is to use a lambda like this:

```
toy |>
  subset(type == "apple") |>
  (\(x){x[sample(nrow(x))]})()
```

I don't know if this is just an example or the code you want to use, if you want to have code that archives the same, just use the sample method for data.frames, that samples rows from a data.frame:

```
toy |> 
  subset(type=="apple") |> 
  sample(1)
```