# Error: Problem with `mutate()` column (...) must be size 15 or 1, not 17192

Tags: r, dplyr, lme4

I am currently trying to plot a the outcome of an `lme4::lmer` function, following [this tutorial](https://www.lcampanelli.org/mixed-effects-modeling-lme4/). I've tried the code in the tutorial, and it works as intended.
In the tutorial a column `pred_dist` is added to the dataset for the fitted function before plotting. When I try this with my own data, I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `pred_dist`.
ℹ `pred_dist = fitted(model0)`.
ℹ `pred_dist` must be size 15 or 1, not 17192.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: sgroup = 578, group = 1.
```

[Sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8g_9L85yGdDujEnkfLOhrosiGrfwqnX/view?usp=sharing)

My code:

```
# Loaded libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(lattice)

# My lmer model. myData is fairly 
model0 <- lmer(outcome ~ (1|group), data=myData, REML = FALSE)
summary(model0)

myData %>% 
    # save predicted values
    mutate(pred_dist = fitted(model0))
```

What I am trying to understand is: What is causing this error message, and how do I resolve it?

---

###### Update:

As per [bouncyball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5619526/bouncyball)'s comment I added
`ungroup()` before `mutate()`. This worked for my initial model, but not the subsequent.
I tried the following:

```
> model1 <- lmer(outcome ~ predictor + (1|group), myData, REML=FALSE) 

> plotVar$pred_dist = fitted(model1). 

Error: Assigned data 'value' must be compatible with existing data. 
✖ Existing data has 17192 rows. 
✖ Assigned data has 16794 rows. 
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

> plotVar %>% ungroup(.) 
          %>% mutate(pred_dist = fitted(model1)) 

Error: Problem with 'mutate()' column 'pred_dist'. 
ℹ 'pred_dist = fitted(model1)'. 
ℹ 'pred_dist' must be size 17192 or 1, not 16794.
```

Comment: better off doing it this way: `myData$pred_dist = fitted(model0)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you have an idea why using `mutate()` generated the error?

Comment: I think `myData` is a grouped data frame. if you put `ungroup()` before the `mutate` call what happens?

Comment: Is there any chance we could have a [mcve]?

Comment: @bouncyball `ungroup()` worked on my first example, but neither solutions worked on subsequent ones (see "Update").

@BenBolker I've tried reducing it as much as possible. I am unable to reproduce the error with smaller datasets, as I am not entirely sure what's causing the issue. That's why I included link to sample dataset that should be able to reduce the errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My very strong guess is that there are two different things going on here: (1) grouping (2) `NA` values.

Let's make up an example that is *both* grouped and contains `NA` values:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
ss <- sleepstudy |> group_by(Subject)
ss$Days[1:5] <- NA

m0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), ss)
```

Try the original code:

```r
ss |> mutate(pred = fitted(m0))
```

> ℹ `pred` must be size 10 or 1, not 175.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Subject = 308.

Try with `ungroup()`:

```r
ss |> ungroup() |> mutate(pred = fitted(m0))
```

> ℹ `pred = fitted(m0)`.
> ℹ `pred` must be size 180 or 1, not 175.

We still get an error, but note that the sizes are different.

Now update the model using `na.action = na.exclude` (this could have been done in the first model, or can be done by setting `options(na.action = "na.exclude")`:

```r
m1 <- update(m0, na.action = na.exclude)
ss |> ungroup() |> mutate(pred = fitted(m1))
```

Comment: I've been looking at your code example, and can't help but notice you use `|>` as a pipe operator instead of `%>%`. I've never seen this syntax before, but the documentation says it's part of `base`. It's certainly a lot quicker to write. Can  `|>` and `%>%` be used fully interchangeably?

Comment: `|>` is new as of R version 4.0. It is *not* interchangeable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe . I like it because it comes without dependencies, although in this case that doesn't matter since we're using `dplyr` anyway.

Comment: `shift` `ctrl` `m` is a great keyboard shortcut (on PCs at least) for `%>%`