# Error: 'mutate()' column must be size 2104 or 1, not 29494

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to sum up the column by sj and hid with `ave`.
My code:
`mutate(h97 = with(df,ave(hhh97,sj,hid,FUN = sum)))`.
I want to get the following result:

```
sj  hid  hhh97  h97
-------------------
1995 1   1      1
1995 1   0      1
1995 2   2      3
1995 2   1      3
```

However, I got the following result and the warning message:

```
sj  hid  hhh97  h97
-------------------
1995 1   1      1
1995 1   0      0
1995 2   2      2
1995 2   1      1
```

```
Problem with `mutate()` column `h97`.
i `h97 = with(df, ave(h97, sj, hid, FUN = sum))`.
i `h97` must be size 2104 or 1, not 29494.
i The error occurred in group 1: sj = 1995.
```

It works with my other columns usaully, but not with this one.
I looked up the question and repsonds in this link,
[Error: Problem with `mutate()` column (...) must be size 15 or 1, not 17192](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185381/error-problem-with-mutate-column-must-be-size-15-or-1-not-17192), and checked the variable h97, there is no NA or NaN. I also don't find any variables with 2104. What can possibly cause this error message, where can size 2104 come from, and how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Since you are using `dplyr` why not `... group_by(...) %>% mutate(h97 = sum(...))`

Comment: Good point! Thanks, it works now. But I'm still curious about the reason that causes this problem.

Comment: Please provide your data.frame with `dput` to create a reproducible example (s. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for further guidelines)