# Native pipe placeholder

Tags: r

I realize this question has been asked before but it's not clicking. There's really no placeholder?

Example:

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(bla = c(1:nrow(.)))
my_mtcars$bla[10] <- NA
my_mtcars$bla[15] <- NA
```

Works:

```
# magritr pipe to return NA rows while debugging a df
my_mtcars %>% filter(!complete.cases(.)) %>% glimpse
```

Does not work:

```
# native piple equivilent
my_mtcars |> filter(!complete.cases(.)) |> glimpse()
```

What's the 'right' way to do what I'm trying to do with the native pipe?

Comment: I'd argue the most "native" way currently is solution 2b in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638063/8107362) answer: e.g. `|> {function(x) grepl("at", x)}()`. Please note the `()` after the anonymous function, since you must call the function, not just define it

Comment: Be careful with your brackets/braces - `my_mtcars |> (\(x) filter(x, !complete.cases(x)))() |> glimpse()`

Comment: Perhaps this example may help, it requires setting the environment variable thelatemail mentioned. `1:5 |> (\(.) .*2)() |> x => (\`<<-\`)(y, x) |> z => (\`*\`)(z, 2) * y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The native R pipe does not use dot.  It always inserts into the first argument.  To get the effect of dot define a function or if it is at the beginning combine it yourself repeating the input (or break it up into two pipelines and do the same -- not shown since doesn't apply here).

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars |>
  (\(x) filter(x, complete.cases(x)))() |>
  summary()
```

or

```
f <- function(x) filter(x, complete.cases(x))
mtcars |> f() |> summary()
```

or

```
filter(mtcars, complete.cases(mtcars)) |> summary()
```

Sometimes `with` can be used to create a workaround.  This creates a list with one element named x and then uses that in the next leg of the pipe.

```
mtcars |>
  list() |>
  setNames("x") |>
  with(filter(x, complete.cases(x))) |>
  summary()
```

Note that you can do this with only base R -- the Bizarro pipe which is not really a pipe but looks like one.

```
mtcars ->.;
  filter(., complete.cases(.)) ->.;
  summary(.)
```

### Update

Since this question appeared R has added a _ placeholder so the `with` example could be shortened to:

```
# needs R 4.2 or later
mtcars |>
  list(x = _) |>
  with(filter(x, complete.cases(x))) |>
  summary()
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure that the way you use complete.cases with the native pipe is robust? See the answer to my post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72801062/2952838 . I think you would experience problems if in the tibble there was a column named "x".

Comment: You can choose the name to be whatever you want.  You don't have to use x.  Use .x or something else unlikely to conflict if you are worried.

Comment: Right, but if you look at the link I posted, it appears that with a simple !!x, you avoid any possible conflict.

Comment: rlang only works in tidyverse so it is not a general solution.

Comment: With `_` placeholder you need to pass the name of the argument that will receive the `_` placeholder. Like `x = _` in above case.