# ggplot mirrored geom_bars customized colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, geom-bar, mirror

I am plotting max_temperature (mean_tmax) against rainfall (mean_rain) in a mirrored barplot: max temp displayed upwards, rain values downwards on the negative scale. These two are stored in the "name" variable.
To highlight the highest values out of the 32 years plotted, I created two vectors colVecTmax, colVecRain. They return a color vector of length 32 each, with the index of max values marked differently.

But when adding these two vectors to fill within geom_bar(), it turns out that ggplot stops counting the top after 16 bars, and moves down to the negative scale to continue. So it does not count by the name (mean_tmax, or mean_rain) variable.
This messes up the plot, and I am not sure how to get ggplot count through on the top bars for max_temperature first, coloring by colVecTmax, and then move down to do the same for rain on the negative scale with colVecRain[image].

Can anyone give a hint on how to solve this?

```
colVecTmax <- rep("orange",32)
colVecTmax[which.max(as.numeric(unlist(df.long[df.long$place=="sheffield" & df.long$name == "mean_tmax",4])))] <- "blue"

colVecRain <- rep("grey",32)
colVecRain[which.max(as.numeric(unlist(df.long[df.long$place=="sheffield" & df.long$name == "mean_rain",4])))] <- "blue"
  
ggplot(df.long[df.long$name %in% c('mean_rain', 'mean_tmax'), ] %>% filter(place== "sheffield")%>%
         group_by(name) %>% mutate(value = case_when(
           name == 'mean_rain' ~ value/10 * -1,
           TRUE ~ value)) %>% mutate(place==str_to_sentence(placenames)) %>%
         mutate(name = recode(name,'mean_rain' = "rainfall" ,  "mean_tmax" =  "max temp"))
         , aes(x = yyyy, y = value, fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity", fill=c(colVecTmax,colVecRain))+
  labs(x="Year", y=expression("Rain in cm, temperature in ("*~degree *C*")"))+
  geom_smooth(colour="black", lwd=0.5,se=F)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-30, 30 , 5))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2025, 5))+
  guides(fill= guide_legend(title=NULL))+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Max temperature", "Rainfall"))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=T), res=96)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot2` there are much easier and less error prone ways to assign colors. Instead of creating color vectors which you pass to the `color` or `fill` argument you could simply map on aesthetics (which you basically already have done) and assign your desired colors using a manual scale, e.g. `scale_fill_manual`. The same approach works fine when you want to highlight some values. To this end you could create additional categories, e.g. in the code below I add `"_max"` to the `name` for the observations with the max temperature or rainfall and assign your desired `"blue"` color to these categories. As doing so will add additional categories I use the `breaks` argument of `scale_fill_manual` so that these max categories will not show up in the legend.

Using some fake random example data:

```
# Create example data
set.seed(123)
df.long <- data.frame(
  name = rep(c("mean_rain", "mean_tmax"), each = 30),
  place = "sheffield",
  yyyy = rep(1991:2020, 2),
  value = c(runif(30, 40, 100), runif(30, 12, 16))
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df_plot <- df.long %>%
  filter(name %in% c("mean_rain", "mean_tmax")) |>
  filter(place == "sheffield") %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    name == "mean_rain" ~ -value / 10,
    TRUE ~ value
  )) |>
  # Maximum values
  group_by(name) |>
  mutate(name = ifelse(abs(value) >= max(abs(value)), paste(name, "max", sep = "_"), name))


ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = yyyy, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity") +
  geom_smooth(colour = "black", lwd = 0.5, se = F) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-30, 30, 5), labels = abs) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2025, 5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      mean_rain = "orange", mean_tmax = "grey",
      mean_rain_max = "blue", mean_tmax_max = "blue"
    ),
    labels = c(mean_tmax = "Max temperature", mean_rain = "Rainfall"),
    breaks = c("mean_rain", "mean_tmax")
  ) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = expression("Rain in cm, temperature in (" * ~ degree * C * ")"), fill = NULL) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: this is excellent, many thanks! (also for solving labels = abs).  What is this sign "|>"? 
Does it do the same as pipe %>% does?

Comment: Aw. Sorry. `|>` is the native pipe added to R with version 4.1. But you can replace it with the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`. For more see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe