# select all the rows after specific rows in each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select rows that appear after first `V` (in `action` column) for each `user`.

```
df<-read.table(text="
user   action
1        D
1        D
1        P
1        E
1        V
1        D
1        D
2        E
2        V
2        V
2        P",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)

resutl:
user   action
1       V
1       D
1       D
2       V
2       V
2       P
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `cumsum` in a `group_by` + `filter` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(user) |> 
  filter(cumsum(action == "V") >= 1) |> 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>    user action
#>   <int> <chr> 
#> 1     1 V     
#> 2     1 D     
#> 3     1 D     
#> 4     2 V     
#> 5     2 V     
#> 6     2 P
```

And thanks to the comment by @r2evans this could be simplified by using `cumany`:

```r
df |> 
  group_by(user) |> 
  filter(cumany(action == "V")) |> 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>    user action
#>   <int> <chr> 
#> 1     1 V     
#> 2     1 D     
#> 3     1 D     
#> 4     2 V     
#> 5     2 V     
#> 6     2 P
```

Comment: code golf: `filter(cumany(action == "V"))` in your pipe

Comment: @r2evans. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @TarJae, but I don't think the replacement offers any innovation over stefan's answer: it uses the same premise, and I've occasionally posted non-dplyr answers that inadvertently relied on `cumany`/`cumall`, so I've found that `cumsum(.)>0` is a great macro-replacement for `cumany`.

Comment: lol thanks was on the wrong way with the window function. just removed.

Comment: Thx @r2evans for - once more - teaching me something new.

Comment: thax, just out of curiosity: what is difference between `%>%` and `|>` ?

Comment: `|>` is the native pipe introduced with R 4.1.0. For more on the differences compared to the `magrittr` `%>%` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe

Comment: One additional remark to keep in mind: In general you could as in my code replace `|>` by `%>%`, while unfortunately it does not work always in the reverse direction.