# How to add a new column to the output within an rapply function?

Tags: r, apply

In a nested list with three levels, I need to reach the third level (i.e., resources) and check whether some special characters exist in the data. I use the code below to do it:

```
obj1 <- list(resource = list(bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee"),side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT"), device = c("LLI", "LSM", "GHT"), id = c("AA", "BB", "CC")) %>%  as.data.frame(), cat = list(lab = c("aa", "bb", "cc"), id = c(23, 24, 25)) %>%  as.data.frame())
obj2 <- list(resource = list(bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee"), side = c("LEFT", "LEFT", "LEFT"), device = c("GOM", "LSM", "YYY"), id = c("ZZ", "DD", "FF")) %>%  as.data.frame())

x <- list(foo = c(fer = "wdb", obj1), bar = obj2)


library(tibble)

data.frame(has_invalid_character = x |> rapply(f = \(node) grepl("[^\x01-\x7F]", node)),
           content =  x |> rapply(f = \(node) node)
           )
```

Now I need to add the information included in the `id` column to the row names  so that I can identify where each case happens in my data. for instance, instead of `foo.resource.bodyPart1`, I need to have `foo.resource.bodyPart.AA`. Similarly,  `foo.resource.bodyPart2`, should be replaced by `foo.resource.bodyPart.BB` Could you please advise me on it?

sample output:

```
                             has_invalid_character content
foo.fer                                   FALSE     wdb
foo.resource.bodyPart1.AA                 FALSE     leg
foo.resource.bodyPart2.BB                 FALSE     arm
foo.resource.bodyPart3.CC                 FALSE    knee
foo.resource.side1.AA                     FALSE    LEFT
foo.resource.side2.BB                     FALSE   RIGHT
foo.resource.side3.CC                     FALSE    LEFT
foo.cat.lab1.23                           FALSE     aa
foo.cat.lab1.24                           FALSE     bb
foo.cat.lab1.25                           FALSE     cc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your example data:

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

## ------------------ see (1)
modify_tree(x, leaf = \(node) {
  if(is.data.frame(node) && !is.null(node$id)){
    ids <- node$id
    lapply(node, FUN = \(col) setNames(col, ids))
  } else {
    setNames(node, 'NA')
  }
}) |> 
## ------------------ see (2)
  unlist() |>
  data.frame() |>
  setNames(nm = 'content') |>
  rownames_to_column('parent') |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(frags = strsplit(parent, '\\.'),
         parent = paste(rev(rev(frags)[-1]),collapse =  '.'),
         id = tail(frags, 1)
         ) |>
  select(-frags) |>
  ## filter out the content of the initial id columns:
  filter(!grepl('\\.id', parent)) |>
  ## do the actual scan for unwanted characters:
  mutate(has_invalid_char = grepl('[^\x01-\x7F]', content))
```

(1) this one operates recursively down the nested lists, checking whether the node at hand is a dataframe and bears an ID-column (named "id"). If so, it digests the dataframe by returning each column as a vector, named with the ID-column. *Caution*: currently ignores dataframes without ID-column. If the node is not an ID-ed dataframe, it is returned as a vector with 'NA'-character as ID.

(2) routing reshaping and processing, finally running the character check

```
# A tibble: 22 x 4
# Rowwise: 
   parent                content id    has_invalid_char
   <chr>                 <chr>   <chr> <lgl>           
 1 foo.fer               wdb     NA    FALSE           
 2 foo.resource.bodyPart leg     AA    FALSE           
 3 foo.resource.bodyPart arm     BB    FALSE           
 4 foo.resource.bodyPart knee    CC    FALSE           
 5 foo.resource.side     LEFT    AA    FALSE           
 6 foo.resource.side     RIGHT   BB    FALSE           
 7 foo.resource.side     LEFT    CC    FALSE           
 8 foo.resource.device   LLI     AA    FALSE           
 9 foo.resource.device   LSM     BB    FALSE           
10 foo.resource.device   GHT     CC    FALSE           
# i 12 more rows
```

Comment: Hi, I found the time to get back to this problem. The code runs nicely on my real data but the only thing that is missing is that the row names are not as expected but numbers from 1 to n which leads to an empty  parent column.  Do you have any clues why it might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I entirely follow what you are asking- you said you want a way of identifying the rows where each case happens in your data, and yet you already have that, in the `has.invalid.character` column:

```
                       has_invalid_character content
foo.fer                                FALSE     wdb
foo.resource.bodyPart1                 FALSE     leg
foo.resource.bodyPart2                 FALSE     arm
foo.resource.bodyPart3                 FALSE    knee
foo.resource.side1                     FALSE    LEFT
foo.resource.side2                     FALSE   RIGHT
foo.resource.side3                     FALSE    LEFT
etc.
```

Then, assuming the dataframe is called `df`, you can filter to select only the ones where it equals true with:

```
df[df$has_invalid_character] # data frame with 0 columns and 31 rows
```

To add an ID column you can use

```
df$id <- seq.int(nrow(df))
```

And then `df[df$has_invalid_character]$id` should find the offending IDs.

Update: It sounds like this is what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    mutate(rowname = paste0(str_replace(rowname, "\\d$", ""), ".", content)) %>%
    select(rowname, has_invalid_character)

                      rowname has_invalid_character
1                 foo.fer.wdb                 FALSE
2   foo.resource.bodyPart.leg                 FALSE
3   foo.resource.bodyPart.arm                 FALSE
4  foo.resource.bodyPart.knee                 FALSE
5      foo.resource.side.LEFT                 FALSE
6     foo.resource.side.RIGHT                 FALSE
7      foo.resource.side.LEFT                 FALSE
8     foo.resource.device.LLI                 FALSE
9     foo.resource.device.LSM                 FALSE
10    foo.resource.device.GHT                 FALSE
11         foo.resource.id.AA                 FALSE
12         foo.resource.id.BB                 FALSE
13         foo.resource.id.CC                 FALSE
14             foo.cat.lab.aa                 FALSE
15             foo.cat.lab.bb                 FALSE
16             foo.cat.lab.cc                 FALSE
17              foo.cat.id.23                 FALSE
18              foo.cat.id.24                 FALSE
19              foo.cat.id.25                 FALSE
20  bar.resource.bodyPart.leg                 FALSE
21  bar.resource.bodyPart.arm                 FALSE
22 bar.resource.bodyPart.knee                 FALSE
23     bar.resource.side.LEFT                 FALSE
24     bar.resource.side.LEFT                 FALSE
25     bar.resource.side.LEFT                 FALSE
26    bar.resource.device.GOM                 FALSE
27    bar.resource.device.LSM                 FALSE
28    bar.resource.device.YYY                 FALSE
29         bar.resource.id.ZZ                 FALSE
30         bar.resource.id.DD                 FALSE
31         bar.resource.id.FF                 FALSE
```

Comment: I don't know if I follow. Give an example of what you want

Comment: I realized the problem and updated my question. Does it help?

Comment: @Rara maybe this is what you want (I honestly dunno though)

Comment: if it's not, you need to provide an example output

Comment: Could you please check the sample output I added.