# `.` works with %>% pipe operator, but not with |> pipe operator

Tags: r, tidyverse, pipeline, tidyr

Why the `.`, to indicate the first object that was passed to the function, works with `%>%` operator but not with `|>` operator?

```
> a <- 1:10
> a[2] <- NA
> library(tidyr)
> a %>% replace(is.na(.),11)
 [1]  1 11  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> a |> replace(is.na(.),11)
Error: object '.' not found
```

Comment: Native pipe uses `_` for the argument placeholder. You can check `?"|>"` for more.

Comment: The magrittr and base pipes are superficially similar but actually have very different implementations. The result is that the base pipe provides less 'extra' features. See this article for more info: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/

Comment: @margusl `?|>` gives me `Error: unexpected '|>' in "?|>"`

Comment: @robertspierre, you have to write exactly `?"|>"`, notice that the actual function (`|>`) is quoted.

Comment: Yes, `?"|>"` works. However, `a |> replace(is.na(_),11)` gives `invalid use of pipe placeholder (<input>:1:0)`

Comment: Check @wurli's link for more differences (can't use `_` in nested calls, argument must be named). And also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67633022/646761 for some excellent examples.

Comment: When you nest `is.na()` inside `replace()`, that's a nested call and the base pipe placeholder will not work.