# Using dplyr to summarize data when factor combinations are missing

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

In this example, I am trying to find the average sales per company across country, but there is missing data. If these combinations were present yet coded NA, that would be fine, but instead the combinations themselves are missing, as shown below.

```
raw_data = data.frame(
  company = c("Zamboni","AcmeCo","Zamboni","AcmeCo"),
  country = c("Canada","Canada","USA","Denmark"),
  sales = c(100,50,200,25)
)
```

Because some combinations are missing (e.g., AcmeCo in USA, and Zamboni in Denmark), the calculated means are wrong, because missing data should be treated as 0 not as NA.

```
summarized_data = raw_data %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  summarize(mean_sales = mean(sales))

A tibble: 2 × 2
company mean_sales
<chr>        <dbl>
1 AcmeCo        37.5
2 Zamboni      150
```

Mean for Zamboni should be (100+200+0)/3 = 100, not (100+200)/2 = 150

Mean for AcmeCo should be (50+25+0)/3 = 25, not (50+25)/2 = 37.5

I could calculate the correct answer by:

```
level_count = length(levels(as.factor(raw_data$country)))
  
summarized_data_2 = raw_data %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  summarize(mean_sales = sum(sales)/level_count)
```

But this feels hacky.
It feels like there should be a function for expanding the dataset to populate it with NAs (and from there, with NA -> 0) for each missing combination of company and country.

Comment: Check out `?tidyr::complete` to create missing combinations.

Comment: Something like `raw_data |> complete(company, country, fill = list(sales = 0)) |> ...`

Comment: Looks useful, thank you! BTW what is "|>"? EDIT: Confirmed, that line of code does the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: `|>` is the base pipe, it works [mostly like `%>%`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67633022/903061) but is part of base R since version 4.1.0