# Is there a situation where the magrittr pipe operator %>% works and the native |> does not?

Tags: r, magrittr

I was working on a situation where I had to use (.) to refer to columns. The native one |> didn't work but %>% did work

I expected to change column names of data with
`setNames(c("Region", paste0(colnames(.)[-1], "_22")))`

Comment: Long story short, the magritter pipe supports some `tidyverse` semantic structures that the native R pipe doesn't https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67633022/1315767

Comment: In your case, it looks like you'd need to replace `colnames(.)` with `colnames(_)`.

Comment: Thank you @Mako212.  That web page is very informative

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring