# How to apply a str_extract function to a range of table cells?

Tags: r, regex, selenium-webdriver, apply, stringr

My ultimate goal is to plot a graph with the data source from a Wikipedia table.

I use R/selenium.

I've succeeded in modifying one of the cells:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(netstat)

selenium()

selenium_object <- selenium(retcommand = TRUE, check = F)
selenium_object

binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

#start the server
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                          chromever = "117.0.5938.92",
                          verbose = F,
                          port = free_port())

#create a client object
remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

#open a browser
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%B2%99%E7%94%B0_(%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF)")

webpage_text <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

tables <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(webpage_text),"//table")

df <- readHTMLTable(tables[[3]], Encoding("UTF-8"))

str_extract(df[4,2], "\\d+([.,]\\d+)?+(?<!\\()")
```

The problem is: how to apply the regex function to a range of table cells? And, how to obtain the result in the same df?

My attempt is this but failed:

```
celsius <- str_extract(df[4,2], "\\d+([.,]\\d+)?+(?<!\\()")

apply(df[c(2:3),c(5:8)], c(1,2), celsius)
```

The puzzle is how to get around with the string attribute in `celsius`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a little simpler. You don't need Selenium here as it's a static website so you can use `rvest` to extract the table:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%B2%99%E7%94%B0_(%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF)"

df <- read_html(url) |>
    html_elements(".wikitable") |>
    html_table(header = FALSE) |>
    purrr::pluck(1) |>
    filter(grepl("°C（°F）", X1)) |> # only temperature columns
    # set month names to English for my benefit
    setNames(c("month", month.abb, "annual"))
```

Then to extract the `celsius` temperatures you can use [`tidyr::separate_wider_regex()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html). We can use the pattern c(c = ".+", f = "\(.+\)"), meaning everything before the brackets is Celsius (`"c"`) and everything in brackets is Fahrenheit (`"f`). As you're only interested in the formet, simply `select()` the `c` columns.

```r
df |>
    tidyr::separate_wider_regex(
        cols = Jan:annual, c(c = ".+", f = "\\(.+\\)"),
        names_sep = "_"
    ) |>
    select(month, ends_with("_c")) |>
    # remove _c from the end of the name
    rename_with(\(x) gsub("_c$", "", x)) |>
    # make temperature numeric
    mutate(across(Jan:annual, as.numeric))

# # A tibble: 5 × 14
#   month                 Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec annual
#   <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 歷史最高溫 °C（°F）  27.6  28.6  31.8  33    36.6  36.4  37.5  38.1  36.5  35.1  31.8  28.9   38.1
# 2 平均高溫 °C（°F）    19.3  19.8  22.1  25.7  29    30.8  31.9  31.9  31.1  28.5  24.9  20.9   26.3
# 3 日均氣溫 °C（°F）    15.8  16.5  19.1  22.6  26.1  28.1  28.9  28.6  27.8  25.2  21.5  17.2   23.1
# 4 平均低溫 °C（°F）    12.9  13.9  16.7  20.2  23.7  25.8  26.3  26    25.2  22.6  18.7  14.1   20.5
# 5 歷史最低溫 °C（°F）   2.9   4     4.4  10.2  15.3  19.9  21.3  22.1  19.9  14.4   6.3   4.8    2.9
```

You may also want to put the data in long form. If so just pipe the last value to `tidyr::pivot_longer(-month)`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'm not very familiar with your approach such as the |> (instead of %>%)  and separate_wider_regex. But I'll learn. BTW, what is pluck? A quick check is "a generalised form of [[ " but what is the use in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @ronzenith `|>` is the base R pipe and [generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe) acts like `"%>%`.  `html_table()` returns a list of tables. In this case we want the first one (actually there is only one on the page) so we `pluck()` the first element. You could equally use `el(1)` instead, or outside of a pipe `my_list[[1]]`.

Comment: If I continue using Selenium, I try the following code but failed:

colnames(df) <- df[2,]
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df <- df[c(-1, -2, -10),-1]

df1 <- df
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  str_extract(df1[i,], "\\d+([.,]\\d+)?+(?<!\\()")
}

It's ok to run at individual rows: str_extract(df1[1,], "\\d+([.,]\\d+)?+(?<!\\()") and returns a list. May I know which part is wrong?

Comment: I think Selenium is not the way to go here. It introduces an additional layer of complexity and I don't think you need it here. I'm afraid I don't know specifically what the error you're facing is. My advice would be not to use it unless you need to.