# In dplyr, why does '.' work with `%>%` but not `|>`?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the new pipe in R I came across this error:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(col1 = c(1,2,3),
             col2 = c("a","b","c"))

df |>
  filter(., col2 == "b")

Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `.`.
Caused by error:
! object '.' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

But if I use dplyr's original pipe I get what I expected.

```
df %>%
  filter(., col2 == "b")

# A tibble: 1 × 2
   col1 col2 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     2 b
```

Is this a new behavior or am I just noticing this now? Do I need to go back to using `%>%` when using dplyr functions?

Comment: Comprehensively answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086492/6851825

Comment: Short answer is that the base pipe uses `_` as placeholder instead of `.`