# Generate Combinations of Comma-Separated Characters for Two Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have an (example) **data frame**, including an **identifier** (here "ID") and **two variables of interes**t (here "V1" and "V2"):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"), 
                 V1 = c("A, B, C",  "E"       , "A, F"),
                 V2 = c("H, G"   ,  "C, A"    , "J"))
```

For the two variables (i.e., columns) of interest, I would like to generate **all potential combinations of comma-separated characters**, identifiable via the identifier, (by *row-wise declination*).

The **result data frame** might look like this (whereby some flexibility in the order and structure is acceptable as long as the combinations are complete):

```
rd <- data.frame(ID = c("Sample 1","Sample 1", "Sample 1", "Sample 1", "Sample 1", "Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 2", "Sample 3", "Sample 3"),
                 V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "E", "E", "A", "F"),
                 V2 = c("H","G","H","G","H","G","C","A","J","J"))
```

**Thank you** very much for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
df  |>
  separate_rows(V1) |>
  separate_rows(V2)
```

Result

```
         ID V1 V2
1  Sample 1  A  H
2  Sample 1  A  G
3  Sample 1  B  H
4  Sample 1  B  G
5  Sample 1  C  H
6  Sample 1  C  G
7  Sample 2  E  C
8  Sample 2  E  A
9  Sample 3  A  J
10 Sample 3  F  J
```

Comment: Perfect. I guess `|>` should be replaced by `%>%`, right? Otherwise, it works :)

Comment: If you are using an R version since v4.1.0 in May 2021, it includes the "base pipe" that uses `|>`. In many simple situations like this, equivalent to `%>%`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe/72086492#72086492