# Dividing values from categories A, B, C based on category D whitout using pivot_wider

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In the example dataframe below, I want to subtract the "revenue" of entries in category "D" from the revenue (of the same product) in entries of categories "A", "B" and "C". The actual dataframe has a bunch of other columns and I need to do this many times, so using pivot_wider operations is a bit inneficient. Is there a quick way to do this?

```
product category revenue
0001    A        78
0001    B        98
0001    C        103
0001    D        95
0002    A        81
 :      :        :
```

Results I'd like for the example dataframe:

```
product category revenue
0001    A        -7
0001    B        3
0001    C        8
0001    D        95
 :      :        :
```

What I've been doing so far:

```
df = df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = revenue)
df[,2:4] = df[,2:4] - df$D %>% as.data.frame()
df = df %>% pivot_longer(2:5, names_to = 'category', values_to = 'revenue')
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Thank for accepting most of the answers ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df |>
  mutate(
    result = ifelse(category == "D", revenue, revenue - revenue[category == "D"]),
    .by = product
  )
#   product category revenue result
# 1       1        A      78    -17
# 2       1        B      98      3
# 3       1        C     103      8
# 4       1        D      95     95
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'product category revenue
0001    A        78
0001    B        98
0001    C        103
0001    D        95', header = T)
```

Comment: three seconds ...

Comment: @r2evans So much extra time typing out `group_by(product) |>` and `|> ungroup()` when `.by = product` will do ;)

Comment: (Not to mention a nicer job with sample data)

Comment: I thought so too (your `.by=` mention), but three of my last `dplyr` answers included `.by=` and none of the OPs had `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer, so they reported that the answer did not work. Now it seems I either pay the price of adding `group_by()`+`ungroup()`, or I pay the price adding a comment of `# requires dplyr_1.1.0 or newer` (7 characters longer). Or I just game it :-/

Comment: I was going to say that's really surprising, but just checked that dates and 1.1.0 is just over a year old. I would have guessed at least 2 years. `.by` is such a nice feature it's too bad they didn't have it from the start. (My guess is it felt too close to `data.table`...)

Comment: Funny ... but perhaps true. It does appear that the two dialects sometimes compete and sometimes feed off each other. I really appreciate the referential semantics and speed of `data.table` but things like `tidyr::pivot_*` seem way easier than the combination of `patterns(.)` and `measure(.)` that are different-enough that I often just accept `data.table`+`tidyr`. \*shrug*

Comment: Thanks! this worked well. What is this |> operator? I've never used it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67633022/3358272

Comment: @ThéodoreTargerian basically the same as `%>%` but built in to base R.