# How can I access column names of an intermediate step in a pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to change a column name in an intermediate step of a pipeline.  Seems like I'm missing something simple.

I can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

temp <- starwars[1:5,1:5]
temp <- set_names(temp,c("person",names(temp)[-1]))
```

This is what I want:

```
temp
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   person         height  mass hair_color skin_color 
#>   <chr>           <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 Luke Skywalker    172    77 blond      fair       
#> 2 C-3PO             167    75 <NA>       gold       
#> 3 R2-D2              96    32 <NA>       white, blue
#> 4 Darth Vader       202   136 none       white      
#> 5 Leia Organa       150    49 brown      light
```

But I can't do this:

```
temp <- starwars[1:5,1:5] |> 
  set_names(c("person",names(~.)[-1]))
temp
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   person         person person person person     
#>   <chr>           <int>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      
#> 1 Luke Skywalker    172     77 blond  fair       
#> 2 C-3PO             167     75 <NA>   gold       
#> 3 R2-D2              96     32 <NA>   white, blue
#> 4 Darth Vader       202    136 none   white      
#> 5 Leia Organa       150     49 brown  light
```

Created on 2024-02-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [the differences between the base pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086492/903061). The base pipe uses `_` as a placeholder, not `.`,  it does not allow the placeholder to be repeated, and it does not allow the placeholder in a nested call. So you've got a few things going against you in this attempt; you may have more luck with `%>%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already attached the `dplyr` package so is there any reason `rename_with` wouldn't work?

```r
starwars[1:5,1:5] |>
  rename_with(~ "Person", .cols = 1)
```

You can specify any [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) helper to pick the column. Here I selected the column by index.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

```
starwars[1:5,1:5] |> 
  (\(x) set_names(x, c("person", names(x)[-1])))()
  
#   person         height  mass hair_color skin_color 
#   <chr>           <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      
# 1 Luke Skywalker    172    77 blond      fair       
# 2 C-3PO             167    75 NA         gold       
# 3 R2-D2              96    32 NA         white, blue
# 4 Darth Vader       202   136 none       white      
# 5 Leia Organa       150    49 brown      light
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `select` to rename the column by position:

```
starwars[1:5,1:5] |>
  select(person = 1, everything())
```