# Using purrr:map and dplyr::mutate with input from nested and non nested column

Tags: r, date, dplyr, purrr

I'm doing a project combining input from two datasets. I would like to do calculations based on data from both datasets. For each `id` in `df` there are 0-3 rows with corresponding `id` in `events`.

Sample data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,        ~date,
  1L, "2010-01-01", 
  2L, "2010-01-02",
  3L, "2010-01-03",
  4L, "2010-01-04",
  5L, "2010-01-05",
  6L, "2010-01-06",
  7L, "2010-01-07",
  8L, "2010-01-08",
  9L, "2010-01-09",
  10L, "2010-01-10"
) %>% dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date))

event <- tibble::tribble(
~id, ~event,  ~event_date,
1L,    "A", "2009-01-01",
1L,    "B", "2009-06-30",
2L,    "A", "2011-01-01",
4L,    "A", "2006-01-01",
4L,    "B", "2008-02-15",
4L,    "B", "2012-12-15",
8L,    "A", "2010-01-08",
9L,    "B", "2010-03-30"
) %>% dplyr::mutate(event_date = as.Date(event_date))
```

Since I want to keep the number of rows in `df` unchanged, my approach was to use `dplyr::nest_join`.

```
df_nest <- dplyr::nest_join(df,event)
```

I then want to find the first `event_date` after `date`. This is where it gets ugly. I have tried using `dplyr::rowwise()` and `purrr::map2()`. With `purrr:map2()` I managed to get almost what I want with the following code which also gives me an error because `min()` gets no input if all dates in `event_date` is less than or equal to `date`.

```
df_nest %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    first_event_after = purrr::map2(
      .x = event,
      .y = date,
      ~ if(length(.x$event_date) > 0){
        .x %>% filter(event_date > .y) %>% pull(event_date) %>% min()
      } else {NA}
    )
  ) -> df_nest_dates
```

Any ideas? I feel that the `purrr::map` functions can be really useful in this scenario but fail to apply them in a good way. Am I wrong to even consider using `purrr:map`? I've tried `dplyr::rowwise()` as well but wasn't able to write a formula combining comparing `event[["event_date"]]` with `date`.

I've thought of the following solution which gives me the desired result, but that doesn't give me the nested data for other calculations. The purpose of this question is to understand how to take advantage of the `purr::map/map2/pmap` functions.

```
left_join(event,df) %>% filter(event_date > date) %>% arrange(date) %>% distinct(id, .keep_all = T) %>% left_join(df,.)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your `map` queries, but you can get your desired result more easily using a rolling join: `df %>% left_join(event, join_by(id, closest(date < event_date)))`.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not join as mentioned by @lotus and *then* nest?

Comment: Thanks @lotus, I didn't know about rolling joins but read about them after reading your comment and they seem really useful.

Comment: @LMc The reason would be that I want to keep all events in the nest for further evaluations which wouldn't be the case with nesting after a rolling join if I understand correctly. (Interested in total events after, any events before and events on the same date as well in some cases).

Comment: @Morgan It would produce the same output with much less of a headache. I add this option to my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this calculation within the nest I think the simplest (and preferred) solution that I mentioned in the comments is to join and then nest:

```r
semi_join(event, df, by = join_by("id", closest(event_date > date))) |>
  select(id, first_date_after = event_date) |>
  right_join(event, by = "id") |> 
  nest_join(x = df, y = _, by = "id", name = "event")
```

---

#### Top level tibble

If you want to store this information in the top level:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df_nest |>
  mutate(x = map2(date, event, \(d, e) semi_join(e, tibble(dt = d), join_by(closest(event_date > dt))))) |>
  hoist(x, "event_date") |> 
  select(-x)
```

`semi_join` is a specific type of *filtering* join, which is handy here because not only does it allow for filtering but it also allows for the use of certain types of inequality, rolling, etc. joins mentioned by @lotus. Unfortunately, `date` is passed as a date vector and not a tibble (which is needed for joining hence the `tibble` call).

I used `tidyr::hoist` to pull that column up into the top-level data frame, but this answer would look different if you were trying to store this value within the nested `event` tibble-column.

**Output**

```r
      id date       event            event_date
   <int> <date>     <list>           <date>    
 1     1 2010-01-01 <tibble [2 × 2]> NA        
 2     2 2010-01-02 <tibble [1 × 2]> 2011-01-01
 3     3 2010-01-03 <tibble [0 × 2]> NA        
 4     4 2010-01-04 <tibble [3 × 2]> 2012-12-15
 5     5 2010-01-05 <tibble [0 × 2]> NA        
 6     6 2010-01-06 <tibble [0 × 2]> NA        
 7     7 2010-01-07 <tibble [0 × 2]> NA        
 8     8 2010-01-08 <tibble [1 × 2]> NA        
 9     9 2010-01-09 <tibble [1 × 2]> 2010-03-30
10    10 2010-01-10 <tibble [0 × 2]> NA
```

### Nested tibble

If you want to store it in the nested tibble column then you can add it back in from the top level:

```r
df_nest |>
  mutate(x = map2(date, event, \(d, e) semi_join(e, tibble(dt = d), join_by(closest(event_date > dt))))) |>
  hoist(x, "event_date") |>
  mutate(event = map2(event_date, event, \(d, e) mutate(e, first_date_after = d))) |> 
  select(-c(x:event_date))
```

Or here is an option with a small helper function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

find_first <- function(dat, dt) {
  if (nrow(dat) == 0) {
    return(structure(integer(0), class = "Date"))
  } else {
    first_date <- semi_join(dat, tibble(dt = dt), join_by(closest(event_date > dt))) |>
      pull(event_date)
    if (length(first_date)) {
      return(first_date)
    } else {
      return(NA_Date_)
    }
  }
}

df_nest |>
  mutate(event = map2(date, event, \(d, e) mutate(e, find_first_date = find_first(e, d))))
```

This helper function handles 3 senarios:

1. `event` is an empty tibble. In this case it returns an empty date vector.
2. If `event` is not empty and a first date can be found that is returned.
3. If `event` is not empty and a first date cannot be found then `NA_date_` is returned.

**Output**

Note: `event` is now a three-column tibble.

```r
      id date       event           
   <int> <date>     <list>          
 1     1 2010-01-01 <tibble [2 × 3]>
 2     2 2010-01-02 <tibble [1 × 3]>
 3     3 2010-01-03 <tibble [0 × 3]>
 4     4 2010-01-04 <tibble [3 × 3]>
 5     5 2010-01-05 <tibble [0 × 3]>
 6     6 2010-01-06 <tibble [0 × 3]>
 7     7 2010-01-07 <tibble [0 × 3]>
 8     8 2010-01-08 <tibble [1 × 3]>
 9     9 2010-01-09 <tibble [1 × 3]>
10    10 2010-01-10 <tibble [0 × 3]>
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer which solves my problem and gives a lot of extra information that I will have to digest. A side question: As you see I am using the `%>%` pipe and `~ .x .y` functions but notice that the `|>` pipe and `\(x,y)` functions are used in your answer and newer documentation and cheat sheets (mine was old). Would it be preferred to change my code to the new standard? Should I also do so in my question?  From what I can find there seems to still be some advantages with the magrittr pipe. Is this true or should it be abandoned?

Comment: @Morgan these are great questions and I do not think there is a black and white answer. I have noticed many of these trends and have gravitated towards implementing them. There are [many differences between `|>` and `%>%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086492/6382434). So use case is important. `~ .x .y` is very easy to write but it is not very explicit (many new users do not understand where these references come from) and there is a step involved to convert that formula into a function. All that said, I do not think there is any need to update your question!

Answer (score 1):

I think more elegant solutions would be possible if you didnt need to retain the original nested structure, but as you do since you want to perform other calculations, it does become a bit awkward dealing with the nesting, but I think its workable and about readable.

I use rowwise() as an appropriate nest compatible way to get mutate to work as we would prefer, then you can build up the calculation you want;

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id,        ~date,
  1L, "2010-01-01", 
  2L, "2010-01-02",
  3L, "2010-01-03",
  4L, "2010-01-04",
  5L, "2010-01-05",
  6L, "2010-01-06",
  7L, "2010-01-07",
  8L, "2010-01-08",
  9L, "2010-01-09",
  10L, "2010-01-10"
) |> mutate(date = as.Date(date))

event <- tribble(
  ~id, ~event,  ~event_date,
  1L,    "A", "2009-01-01",
  1L,    "B", "2009-06-30",
  2L,    "A", "2011-01-01",
  4L,    "A", "2006-01-01",
  4L,    "B", "2008-02-15",
  4L,    "B", "2012-12-15",
  8L,    "A", "2010-01-08",
  9L,    "B", "2010-03-30"
) |> mutate(event_date = as.Date(event_date))
( df_nest <- nest_join(df,event,
                              name = "event_df"))

df_nest |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    first_valid_row = list(slice_min(
      filter(
        event_df,
        event_date >= date
      ),
      order_by = event_date,
      n = 1
    )),
    event = ifelse(nrow(first_valid_row) > 0,
                   first_valid_row$event, NA_character_
    ),
    event_date = { # dates are weird and easy for their type to get lost
      \(x)if (nrow(x) > 0) {
        x$event_date
      } else {
        NA_Date_
      }
    }(first_valid_row)
  )
```

```
 A tibble: 10 × 6
# Rowwise: 
      id date       event_df         first_valid_row  event event_date
   <int> <date>     <list>           <list>           <chr> <date>    
 1     1 2010-01-01 <tibble [2 × 2]> <tibble [0 × 2]> NA    NA        
 2     2 2010-01-02 <tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> A     2011-01-01
 3     3 2010-01-03 <tibble [0 × 2]> <tibble [0 × 2]> NA    NA        
 4     4 2010-01-04 <tibble [3 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> B     2012-12-15
 5     5 2010-01-05 <tibble [0 × 2]> <tibble [0 × 2]> NA    NA        
 6     6 2010-01-06 <tibble [0 × 2]> <tibble [0 × 2]> NA    NA        
 7     7 2010-01-07 <tibble [0 × 2]> <tibble [0 × 2]> NA    NA        
 8     8 2010-01-08 <tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> A     2010-01-08
 9     9 2010-01-09 <tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> B     2010-03-30
10    10 2010-01-10 <tibble [0 × 2]> <tibble [0 × 2]> NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how `rowwise()` can be used in my scenario. I don't really understand how `filter(event_df,event_date >= date)` can use both `event_date` from `event_df` and `date` from `df_nest`. Obviously it works but I thought that date would have to exist in the `event_df` tibble for it to work or else be called by `event_df$event_date`. I also have a question regarding the syntax for the `event_date` column, from what I've read before anonymous functions are called when wrapped in parenthesis. Is wrapping with `{}` equal to parenthesis or does it differ somehow?

Comment: about anonymous functions 
`add_1 <- function(x){x+1}`
`add_1_same <- \(x){x+1}`

`add_1(1)`
`add_1_same(1)`
`\(x){x+1}(1) # just echoes back`
`{\(x){x+1}}(1) # works as expected`