Convert strings into indicator/dummy columns in R dataframe
I have data from a survey, where multiple options are possible. So in one cell, you have multiple answers, separated by columns. There are many questions, and most have long string answers. I want to split the cells into columns, where variable names are the answers and values are 1 or 0 depending on whether the answer contain it.
Below is an example of a trivial question, with very simple strings, and the desired result.
data <- data.frame("v1" = c(c("apple, orange"),c("apple, melon"),c("banana")))

result <- data.frame("apple" = c(1,1,0),
                   "orange" = c(1,0,0),
                   "melon" = c(0,1,0),
                   "banana" = c(0,0,1))

I guess the whole process should be something like:

for each variable/question with multiple answers
find and store unique values across data
create new vectors with those names
string-search each variable name within each cell and mark as 1/0 if find or not

Here is my incomplete attempt, for one variable only:
a <- strsplit(input$v1, split = ", ")
b <- # missing step 
c <- unique(b)
c <- c("apple","orange","melon","banana") # manually for now
d <- as.character(unlist(c))
e <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(c), nrow = nrow(input)))
colnames(e) <- d
f <- cbind(input,e)
for (Variable in c) {
  for (Value in d) {
    input$Variable <- ifelse(grepl(Value,input$v1, fixed = TRUE),1,0)
  }
}
input$v1 <- NULL

Any suggestions?

library(qdapTools)
library(dplyr)

data |>
  mutate(v1 = strsplit(v1, ", ")) |>
  (\(x) mtabulate(x[["v1"]]))()
#   apple banana melon orange
# 1     1      0     0      1
# 2     1      0     1      0
# 3     0      1     0      0

If you have multiple columns it might be easier to concatenate them first:
data <- data.frame(v1 = c("apple, orange","apple, melon","banana"),
                   v2 = c("tomato", "spinach, broccoli", "cucumber"))

data |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(v = pick(starts_with("v")) |> paste(collapse = ", ") |> strsplit(", ")) |>
  (\(x) bind_cols(data, mtabulate(x[["v"]])))()

#              v1                v2 apple banana broccoli cucumber melon orange spinach tomato
# 1 apple, orange            tomato     1      0        0        0     0      1       0      1
# 2  apple, melon spinach, broccoli     1      0        1        0     1      0       1      0
# 3        banana          cucumber     0      1        0        1     0      0       0      0

If you have a moderately sized data frame you might find that rowwise() is a particularly slow operation. While readable, it might be better to replace it with another function that works down rows. Also, bind_cols() is not necessary if you do not want to retain the original values from data.

Another possibility is to use splitstackshape, which has functionality for this exact situation:
library(splitstackshape)

# single column
cSplit_e(data, "v1", type = "character", fill = 0L)
#              v1                v2 v1_apple v1_banana v1_melon v1_orange
# 1 apple, orange            tomato        1         0        0         1
# 2  apple, melon spinach, broccoli        1         0        1         0
# 3        banana          cucumber        0         1        0         0

# multiple columns
lapply(c("v1", "v2"), \(x) cSplit_e(data, x, type = "character", fill = 0L, drop = T)) |>
  do.call(cbind, args = _)
#                  v2 v1_apple v1_banana v1_melon v1_orange            v1 v2_broccoli v2_cucumber v2_spinach v2_tomato
# 1            tomato        1         0        0         1 apple, orange           0           0          0         1
# 2 spinach, broccoli        1         0        1         0  apple, melon           1           0          1         0
# 3          cucumber        0         1        0         0        banana           0           1          0         0


library(tidyverse)
data |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  separate_longer_delim(v1, ", ") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = v1, values_from = v1, values_fn = ~1, values_fill = 0)
  

Result
# A tibble: 3 × 5
    row apple orange melon banana
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     1      1     0      0
2     2     1      0     1      0
3     3     0      0     0      1


Why use the native pipe operator instead of tidyverse's one %>%?

They are in many simple cases interchangeable so it’s a matter of taste/convenience. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe  Hadley suggests using the base pipe where possible, eg https://r4ds.hadley.nz/workflow-style#sec-pipes

Ah ok, thanks. Any way to change the name of new variables at creation point? In my case, I have long textual answers from humans. Something like v2, v3, v4, etc...

library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  separate_rows(v1) %>% 
  group_by(v1, ID) %>% # I used both v1 and ID in case you can have multiple occurences of the same fruit (ex. 'orange, banana, orange') and you are interested in the counts, otherwise you can use ID only
  summarise(value = n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = v1, values_from = value, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-ID) # in case you want to remove the ID column created to be used in group_by and id_cols

# `summarise()` has grouped output by 'v1'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#  apple banana melon orange
#  <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
# 1  1      0     0      1
# 2  1      0     1      0
# 3  0      1     0      0

