Generate new variable using reference to cell within pipe
I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe, with values coming from a specific cell of the same df. I want to do this within a pipe, without referring explicitely to the original dataframe.
In the example below, I would like to replace df[2,3] with an implicit reference to the df in the pipe. I tried  .[2,3] but it doesn't work.
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  B = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
  C = c(9, 10, 11, 12)
)

df <- df |> 
  mutate(D = df[2,3])


You were close. Try:
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  B = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
  C = c(9, 10, 11, 12)
)

df <- df |> 
  mutate(D = paste(df[2,3]))

df
  A B  C  D
1 1 5  9 10
2 2 6 10 10
3 3 7 11 10
4 4 8 12 10


In case you do not want to usedf[2,3] we can use magrittr pipe in dplyr, for instance.
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(D = paste(.[2,3]))

df
  A B  C  D
1 1 5  9 10
2 2 6 10 10
3 3 7 11 10
4 4 8 12 10



It works with the old pipe operator %>% but not with the new one |>. Any idea why or solution?

This answer gives a good overview on this topic and the evolvement of the native pipe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086492/11809780
Regarding your question, I guess this may be considered a nested call which, as of base 4.3.0, is not allowed (yet).

This type of direct refference is kind of strange with dpplyr::mutate, because it adds new variables that are functions of existing variables (dplyr overview). If your columns values or positions change, this may became a problem.
That said, you can make it with bind_cols too. As another option, I use .$C[2] instead of .[2, 3], wich will mitigate a potential problem if this column moves.
df <- relocate(df, C, .before = 1)

> df
   C A B
1  9 1 5
2 10 2 6
3 11 3 7
4 12 4 8 
 
df %>% 
  bind_cols(D = .$C[2])

Output:
   C A B  D
1  9 1 5 10
2 10 2 6 10
3 11 3 7 10
4 12 4 8 10

