Stacked barplot with date, group and frequency (in base R)
I have data that looks like this:
         Date Title Units
1  2023-11-18     L     2
2  2023-11-19     L     1
3  2023-11-23     L     1
4  2023-11-27     L     2
5  2023-11-28     L     1
6  2023-12-07     L     1
7  2024-01-24     A     1
8  2024-01-25     A     1
9  2024-01-27     A     1
10 2024-01-28     A     3
... etc.

I want to create a stacked barplot using base R that looks like this (not the colors etc., just the principle):

I tried:
> barplot(Units ~ Title, obp)
Error in barplot.formula(Units ~ Title, obp) : 
  duplicated categorical values - try another formula or subset

I don't understand how to do this! (No ggplot2!)

Sample data:
obp <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(19679, 19680, 19684, 19688, 
19689, 19698, 19746, 19747, 19749, 19750, 19752, 19753, 19753, 
19756, 19764, 19767, 19770, 19778, 19782, 19782, 19790, 19793, 
19795, 19800, 19802, 19803, 19803, 19803, 19804, 19805, 19805, 
19805, 19807, 19809, 19809, 19809, 19810, 19812, 19815, 19816, 
19821, 19828, 19829, 19829, 19831, 19831, 19835, 19836, 19837, 
19838, 19839, 19840, 19842, 19848, 19849, 19850, 19851, 19854, 
19855, 19856, 19858, 19858, 19859, 19860, 19862, 19865, 19868, 
19870, 19871, 19871, 19872, 19877, 19878, 19878, 19883, 19884, 
19884, 19886, 19891, 19891), class = "Date"), Title = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L), levels = c("A", 
"D", "L", "C"), class = "factor"), Units = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))


Aggregate the data first to make sure there are no repeated categorical variables. Then pipe to barplot.
I also add a color argument. Instead of colors 2 to 5 you can choose others from, for instance, colors().
colrs <- obp$Title |> levels()
colrs <- setNames(2:5, colrs)

aggregate(Units ~ Title + Date, obp, sum) |>
  barplot(Units ~ ., data = _, beside = FALSE, col = colrs)


Created on 2024-06-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Nice, thank you! Where can I learn about |> and _?

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086492/20002111 And it's simple: in base, the LHS is piped as first argument to the RHS (default), if not specified otherwise (like ..., data = _)
