Why Does Native Pipe Operator |> Fail with Placeholder _ in R?
I am trying to compare the %>% with the native |>, but I am not too sure why sometimes it only works for %>%. Here is an example:
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)


# Create the sample vector:
sample_value <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5)

It works when using pipe operator and its placeholder . from the magrittr package:
# With pipe operator and its placeholder (.):
sample_value %>%
  replace(list = is.na(.), values = 4) |> 
  str_flatten_comma()

I get expected result: [1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5"
But when I use the native pipe operator |> and its placeholder _,  it didn't work:
# With native pipe operator and its placeholder (_):
sample_value |> 
  replace(list = is.na(_), values = 4) |> 
  str_flatten_comma()

I get a warning:
Error in str_flatten_comma(replace(sample_value, list = is.na("_"), values = 4)) : 
  invalid use of pipe placeholder (<input>:3:0)

I am not sure what has caused the issue and I'd appreciate your thoughts. Thank you.

There was a long discussion in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe/67638063#67638063

Since replace(list = is.na(_), values = 4) is nested. Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe/72086492#72086492 Since then some functionality came with latest updates of R!

You are attempting to use sample_value twice in the call to replace().  You only mention it once, but your code only makes sense if you want the x argument to also be sample_value.  You can't do that with the base pipe.  The fact that magrittr pipes do it is one of the irritating oddities of those pipes.


Placeholder needs named argument, 2) Placeholder can only appear once, 3) Nested calls are not allowed


In base you could use: sample_value |> (\(.) replace(., list = is.na(.), values = 4))() |> str_flatten_comma()
