Can I use the LHS multiple times in an R |> pipe?
I'm trying to mutate some data with dpylr, but am stumbling across my unfamiliarity with pipes. Is there any way to get the LHS data as an argument to nrow here?
data <- bigger_frame |>
  select(my_col) |>
  mutate(rand_col = sample(100, size=nrow($what_goes_here?), replace = TRUE)

I'm not 100% certain that's syntactically correct overall, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do. I want to use the LHS as the data argument to sample, but also get the number of rows in it for the sample's size. All I'm trying to do is add a column of random numbers to an existing data frame.

Your code does not make much sense to me. Why not nrow(data)? There is _$x. And more, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe/72086492#72086492 You might need to adapt select(>more_to_stay<).

Use the underscore placeholder available since R 4.2.0 which requires function arguments to be named and not by position.

No, you can't use the LHS more than once.  The base pipe is equivalent to calling the RHS with the LHS as an argument.  If you put  the LHS in twice, you would evaluate it twice, and that's not what the pipe should do.  The magrittr pipe allows multiple uses, because it is like a chain of statements, evaluating each part and substituting it into the next part after evaluation, not before.

To get the number of rows when using dplyr, you should use n(), e.g. sample(100, size=n(), replace = TRUE) - avoid using something like nrow(data) as it can fail (e.g. if the data is grouped).
